# How to transfer database info to another controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, controller

My goal: user chooses an item from list (list of items from database) and this item will show on another page.

I want to transfer key from database, that is chosen in one controller and have access of this chosen key from another controller.

My database was created by Entity Framework, one of my model.

My model of database:

```
public class Apartment
{
    // id of apartment
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }

    // quantity in apartment
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    // class of apartment
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
    public Classes Class { get; set; }

    // price of apartment
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    // start of book apartment
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    // end of book apartment
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

// Class apartment in enum
public enum Classes
{
    Economy,
    Standard,
    Luxury
}
```

View, where user chooses his apartment:

```
foreach (Hotel.DAL.Entities.Apartment a in Model)
{
    <div id="ap" class="col-md-3">
        <p>Class: @a.Class
        <p>Quantity: @a.Quantity человек
        <p>Price for one day: @a.Price $

        @if (ViewBag.TimeInt != null)
        {
            ViewBag.FullPrice = a.Price * ViewBag.TimeInt;
            <p>Full price: @ViewBag.FullPrice $</p>
        }

        @if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
                <p>
                    <button value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('/Home/Confirm')" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@a.ApartmentId" />
                </p>
            </form>
        }
</div>
}
```

Hidden type is an input, where I take a value of my key.

Controller method of view:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    ViewData["ClassSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Class" ? "class_desc" : "Class";
    ViewData["PriceSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Price" ? "price_desc" : "Price";

    var p = from s in dbshow.GetList()
            select s;

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "class_desc":
            p = dbshow.GetList().OrderByDescending(s => s.Class);
            break;

        case "price_desc":
            p = dbshow.GetList().OrderByDescending(s => s.Price);
            break;

        default:
            p = dbshow.GetList().OrderBy(s => s.Class);
            break;
    }

    return View(p);
}

// filters to book apartments
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, Classes? Class, int? quantity, DateTime? start, DateTime? end, bool? check)
{
    ViewData["CurrentQuan"] = quantity;
    ViewData["CurrentClass"] = Class;
    ViewData["CurrentStart"] = start;
    ViewData["CurrentEnd"] = end;
    ViewData["CurrentCheck"] = check.GetValueOrDefault();

    ViewData["ClassSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Class" ? "class_desc" : "Class";
    ViewData["PriceSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Price" ? "price_desc" : "Price";

    var aps = from s in dbshow.GetList()
              select s;

    return View(aps);
}
```

Controller that I need to transfer ApartmentId (key) is default:

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
{
    return View();
}
```

I heard that better way to did it by cookies. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a cookie and read the content of the cookie or you can use sessions.
See example: https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/

Or another solution is to save their selection in the database and fetch it where you need it.

**Update:**
Edit the form to post the key to /confirm/ so no need to persit this value in a cookie or a session

Comment: There multiple ways to store and retrieve your key value. You can pick one based on your needs. 1. Use cookies to store the key 2. Add the key to your page query string: it’s very easy to set and get it. 3. Use database queue to store it. Lastly use page sessions: make sure this will not work properly if your application  scales out to multiple machines

Comment: @Moe Jallaq I try to use query string: can you explain, i need to initialize f.ex.: ```string Id = Request.QueryString["id"];``` in my index contoller(method post)?

Comment: Or since you are using mvc:  `return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "MyController", new { input = "myInput"});`

Comment: @Noobie 1 variant i used in my Confirm view and it was localhost error. Second variant: i just changed return string in Confirm controller, and that was wrong adress. Most likely I do not fully understand what you mean. :(

Comment: Oh i just realised, you are posting to '/Home/Confirm/ with a hidden field "key" which i pressume is the key you need? Is that correct? Then in your controller you need to read the data from the form e.g. [FromForm] MyForm form. If the Confirm method is in a different controller you need to specify the controller and the action `<a asp-controller="Speaker" asp-action="Index">All Speakers</a>` and mark the method as POST

Comment: @Noobie yes, you are right, i have ```foreach``` in view, and the buttons and hidden fields are generated inside of the cycle. As you said, I need to create```[HttpPost] ``` controller of Confirm  and write ```<a asp-controller="Speaker" asp-action="Index">All Speakers</a>```action in Confrim View?

Comment: You need to create a POST method to post your form in whichever controller you like, and from this method you can return a view containing the result of this action.

Comment: You can keep your form where it is in your current view. just post to the correct method. See a nice example here: https://jonhilton.net/2017/08/17/how-to-get-data-from-an-html-form-to-your-asp.net-mvc-core-controller/